# How can I create an element based on the element name of the node I’m reading?

Tags: javascript, html

```
var div = document.getElementById("foo");

for(loop = 0; loop < div.childNodes.length; loop++)
{
    document.createElement(div.childNodes[0]); // this isn't possible
}
```

I want to create an element depending on what type is the node I’m reading. Something like:

```
if(div.childNodes[0] == "a")  // this isn't possible
    document.createElement("a");
```

Comment: .nodeName is what u need

Comment: If you want to copy the attributes as well, use `.cloneNode()`. Like `div.childNodes[0].cloneNode()`

Answer (score 0):

`createElement` requires a string argument for the element name. Try

```
document.createElement(div.childNodes[loop].tagName)
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.tagName

Answer (score 0):

You can use `elem.tagName` or `elem.nodeName` to get the element HTML name and create it when needed.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `tagName`

```
document.createElement(div.childNodes[0].tagName);
```